# Where does word 2016 store the data for "Numeral" option?

Tags: microsoft-word

Where does word 2016 store the data for "Numeral" option?
File -> Options -> Advanced -> Under "Show Document Content"
[image]

I couldn't figure it out using Process monitor!
In registry? or in a file? where is that exactly?

Comment: You mean, where is your preference saved? What are you trying to do?

Comment: yes, I want to apply these settings to multiple computers